# Finding Feature Points below a line

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

Sorry for asking this question if it is too silly.

I've feature points corresponding to two image frames. And I wanted to take points below a straight line which is drawn connecting two boarder points. Something like this.

[image]

I wanted to take Points below and upper separately in a vector. Please assist me if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line can be expressed as

```
ly(lx) = y + lx * (y' - y) / (x' - x)
```

An arbitrary point `(px, py)` is above the line if

```
                 py < ly(px)
                 py < y + px * (y' - y) / (x' - x)
             py - y < px * (y' - y) / (x' - x)
(py - y) * (x' - x) < px * (y' - y)   //assuming x' > x
```

You just need to check this relation. If it holds, the point is above the line. If the terms are equal, the point is on the line. If the left term is bigger than the right term, the point is below the line.

Comment: Thank You Very Much @Nico Schertler. Much appreciate your help. Unfortunately, forgotten all the high school maths.